# Neyman-Pearson Condition

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

In the proof of Neyman-Pearson from,

Let $ \pi _0,\pi _1 $  be two populations with probability distributions say $ f_0,f_1 $  (with measure $ \mu  $ ). Then for testing $ H_0:f=f_0 $  against $ H_1:f=f_1 $ , we can define a test $ \phi  $  with a constant $ k $  such that the expectation of the test under the null hypothesis $ H_0:f=f_0 $ denoted as $ E_0 $  is,
$$ E_0\left[ \phi \left( x \right) \right] =\alpha, ~~~~~(level~of~significance) (‎9.5)$$

and,

$$ \phi \left( x \right) =\begin{cases}  1&  when\ f_1\left( x \right) >kf_0\left( x \right)\\  0&  when\ f_1\left( x \right) <kf_0\left( x \right)\\ \end{cases} (9.6)$$

If our test $ \phi  $  satisfies (‎9.5) and (‎9.6) for some $ k $ , then it’s most powerful test for $ H_0 $  against $ H_1 $  at level $ \alpha  $ . What $ f_0\left( x \right) ,\ f_1\left( x \right)  $  mean is that our parameters are defined in terms of input variables.

Casae#1: when $ 0<\alpha <1 $ . Let us define a quantity $ G\left( c \right) $  as,
$ G\left( c \right) =P_0\left\{ f_1\left( x \right) >cf_0\left( x \right) \right\}  $
where $ P_0 $  is under $ H_0 $ . Since $ G\left( c \right)  $  is computed when $H_0 $  is true, so the inequality need to be considered only for the set when $ f_0\left( x \right) >0 $ ,
$P_0\left( \frac{f_1\left( x \right)}{f_0\left( x \right)}>c \right)  $
so, $ 1-G\left( c \right)  $  is a CDF of $ \frac{f_1\left( x \right)}{f_0\left( x \right)} $ , we can let $ y=\frac{f_1\left( x \right)}{f_0\left( x \right)}$ .

**Question**: And how the proof came up with in case $ 0<\alpha <1 $, then $ G\left( c \right) =P_0\left\{ f_1\left( x \right) >cf_0\left( x \right) \right\} $?

**Edit**: Second, since $1-G(c)$ is a CDF, why $G(c)$ is continuous on right and why $\lim_{c\to \infty} G(c)=0$?

Comment: $1-G(c)=P_0\left(\frac{f_1(X)}{f_0(X)}\le c,f_0(X)>0\right)$ is clearly the distribution function of $Y=\frac{f_1(X)}{f_0(X)}\mathbf1_{\{f_0(X)>0\}}$ under $H_0$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom. Amazing explanation although concise. For $ G\left( c \right) =P_0\left\{ f_1\left( x \right) >cf_0\left( x \right) \right\} $, could you please clarify how it was brought up for the case when $0\lt \alpha \lt 1$. I mean why the proof decided to define this quantity specifically and not any other quantity?

Comment: @StubbornAtom. What do you mean please by $\frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)}1_{f_0(X)>0}$ Is this an indicator function? Could you please add why this is under $H_0$?

Comment: The answer to "why the proof decided to define this quantity" lies in the rest of the proof. Have you gone through the entire proof? And yes, I define $Y$ to be $f_1(X)/f_0(X)$ if $f_0(X)>0$ and $Y=0$ otherwise. Then CDF of $Y$ under $H_0$ is $P_0(Y\le c)=P_0\left(Y\le c,f_0(X)>0\right)=P_0\left(\frac{f_1(X)}{f_0(X)}\le c,f_0(X)>0\right)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom. Why it was assumed that for $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$, then $G(c) = P_0 \{f_0(x) \gt c f_0(x)\}$ in the proof above? Second, why you assumed that $f_0(x) > 0$? Finally, do you see why $ \lim_{c\to\infty} G(c)=0$?